# firebase.auth().currentUser is returning null when i re-execute a script in node.js cli

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I m creating a node cli and i m using firebase auth in it

everything is working fine

there is a command to login and when the user executes it asks for credentials. after the submission i get a custom auth token from an api and then i use signinwithcustomtoken and i get value of 'currentUser' as expected.

According to this page [Access Firebase in your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#namespace) i can use firebase client sdk in a node.js app for auth

**Problem**

but as when i execute another command to show profile data and in that when i try to access `firebase.auth().currentUser` it returns null :(

I m not creating any kind of server.

I think firebase is recreating a new instance every time i run a command 
but why doesn't firebase loose instance in angular ?

Answer (score 0):

In Node.js deployments, the default [Auth state persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence) mode is `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE` for security reasons as mentioned at the bottom of the [Modifying the ASP](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence#modifying_the_auth_state_persistence) section. This means that the user state is cleared whenever you close your script.

Prior to logging in with your authentication token, you will need to use the following code to change the mode to match a browser:

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL) // <-- this bit
  .then(function() {
    // Users will now be logged in until they explicitly log out
    return firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(token);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
  });
```

Comment: with that it i get "Error: The current environment does not support the specified persistence type."